# How to seed the apt and/or dpkg database of packages?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I have this system that has a basic Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS installation on it, but no network access. I have this set of deb packages which have been copied to some location on said machine. How do I get dpkg and/or apt to recognise these packages as available?

I thought `$ sudo dpkg --recursive --record-avail` would do it, and it does see each package and reports "Recorded info about …" for each one, but later attempts to `$ sudo apt-get install` or `$ sudo dpkg -i` fail just as before the 'record-avail'. I think I'm close but missing something.

Comment: Have a look at some of the options here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Comment: @muru: A very useful question page indeed. After a fair amount of work on my part, apt-offline turned out to be what I needed.

Comment: Ah, sorry if it was a lot of trouble, I figured one of those answers would apply closely to you case. Could you add an answer here for the benefit of future users, considering it took a bit of work?

Comment: Don't misunderstand me: your suggestion was spot on. Using apt-offline to get the list of missing dependencies for any given package is the first, crucial step in installing said package, whether one is making a partial local repository or feeding apt's cache directly. The main problem I ran into was that, in the absence of any files in /var/lib/apt/lists to start with, both apt and apt-offline conk out without yielding any useful error messages.

If anyone thinks it may be useful, I could expand the answer to detail the steps one must follow.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out one must first copy the repository descriptors (`Packages`, `Sources`, `Release`, `Release.gpg`, `Index`, `Translation-en`) to `/var/lib/apt/lists`. Start by installing `apt-offline`, which has very few dependencies (I was starting from a command-line Ubuntu installation). Once the repository descriptors are in place, both `apt-offline` and `apt` become workable.